# gitlab ci: mysql build and restore db dump

Tags: java, mysql, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

in gitlab.yml I have

```
mysql_build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: rates
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  services:
  - mysql:latest
  image: mysql
  before_script:
  - mysql --version
  script:
  - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql --user=root --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" --host=mysql "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
  - mysql --user=root --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" rates < db/rates_db.sql
```

it is install mysql successfully, but I want to restore sql dump file for accessing it in next stage.

when started this part, I have exception:

```
 - mysql --user=root --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" rates < db/rates_db.sql

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Real application located here

https://gitlab.com/armdev/exchange-rates

How can I restore db in mysql?

Comment: The mysql service runs in a docker container and is accessible with hostname `mysql`. Could you try it with something like this: `mysql --user=root --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" --host=mysql rates < db/rates_db.sql`

Comment: BTW you had it right in the first mysql command so I guess you just forgot to add it in

Comment: Yes, thanks it works:) mysql build is ok. How I should change access to mysql from jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rates ? to jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/rates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

Try this

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE rates
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root

COPY db/rates_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Replace into gitlab-ci.yml

```
mysql_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build . -t <Image name>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, and one question how I should access database? Now I use jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rates , should I use docker port like jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.104:3306/rates?

Comment: If you run the container and the java application inside the same server, you have to do jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.1:3306/rates. But if not you have to add the ip of the server and check that the contanier resolves the ip.

Comment: Please, help me with this problem, i have searched and i don't have found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163415/is-possible-import-db-schema-to-service-mysql-gitlab-ci