# Is possible import DB schema to service mysql gitlab ci?

Tags: mysql, gitlab-ci

I have a project with **nodejs, rethinkdb abd mysql** and I'm try create a `pipeline` file, little by little I have gone creating it. But i need import my database schema(schema.sql) and I could not did, i search info about but nothing work me

#### My pipeline file

```
variables:
  PORT: "80"
  DB_HOST: "webservice_db"
  DB_PORT: "28015"
  NODE_ENV: "testing"
  urlSources: "https://example.com"
  hostDomain: "https://example.com"
  domain: "example.com"
  rtDbName: "testRethink"
  portRt: "28015"
  hostRethinkdb: "rethinkdb"
  mysqlPass: "123456"
  hostMysql: "mysql"
  mysqlUSer: 'runner'
  mysqlDbName: "testdb"
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "testdb"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "123456"
  MYSQL_USER: "runner"
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: "123456"
  MYSQL_PORT: "3306"

services:
  - name: rethinkdb:latest
    alias: rethinky
  - name: mysql:latest
    # command:
      # - mysql -urunner -p123456 testdb<./test/schema.sql
    alias: mysqldb

# This folder is cached between builds
# http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - test/

test_db:
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm run importmysql
```

I have my sql file in `/test/schema.sql` but not idea how import that. I hope that somebody with this problem. Thanks ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What about that line `mysql -urunner -p123456 testdb<./test/schema.sql`?

Comment: Hello. I was trying with docs that me see in internet. But that doesn't work